# Performance - generate xml by DOMDocument vs pure string

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am generating a XML string in backend and return it as response to the browser.
The question I have from the performance point of view is, which method is better: to generate the XML by using DOMDocument or generate the XML as string.

For instance, I can generate a simple XML as below

```
$value = 'My Name';
$attribute = 'Mn';
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root>';
$xml .= "<name initialize=\"$attribute\">$value</name>";
$xml .= '</root>';
return $xml;
```

Or I can use DOMDocument as

```
$value = 'My Name';
$attribute = 'Mn';
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$root = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('root'));
$newnode = $xml->createElement('name', $value);
$attrib = $xml->createAttribute('initialize');
$attrib->value = $attribute;
$newnode->appendChild($attrib);
$root->appendChild($newnode);
return $xml->saveXML();
```

*The output might be used in IE compatible view mode or even quirks mode, which I think might be important to compare each mentioned method*
That will be great help if someone could tell me the pros and cons of each one(Performance, speed, etc).
Appreciate it, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Another alternative is [XMLWriter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php)

Comment: A simple benchmark should be easy enough to do me thinks?

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for your comment; Yes, I know there are more alternative, but I am not sure which one really give me a higher or better performance. I wished there was something to show the comparison of each alternative

Comment: Well obviously just using a string is going to be faster.

Comment: @mclaassen - not necessarily because you're constantly allocating more memory for the concatenation, and this can also be problematic if you're working with limited memory

Comment: @MarkBaker Ok. But if it was all in one string it would certainly be faster.

Comment: @MarkBaker You are right; concatenation will cause more memory allocation. I think we cannot say exactly which is faster, it depends on what we have and what we need; right?

Comment: precisely, for generating smaller documents, simple concatenation is the most efficient, though using DOMDocument or XMLWriter has an added bonus of providing a validation check for the xml that you're creating (you won't get errors from concatenation if you try to generate invalid markup); for larger volumes of data (and large documents), XMLWriter is going to give you better memory control

Comment: Thanks a lot; That gives me good information

Comment: Use of a library such as XMLWriter is best. It will handle issues such as escaping of special characters, which "hand-written" XML so often gets wrong, and it may be more efficient than string concatenation which can lead to lots of long copy operations.

Answer (score 2):

I would use string operations. DOM is good for parsing and probably modifying *existing* XML documents. For the creation a plain string operation has less overhead than DOM.

However, there might be still situations where the creation of an xml is more complex and involves multiple components of your application, which share the unfinished XML before rendering. In such situations, DOM might be worth it's overhead.. it depends ...

In the simple example which you have shown in the question, I would use string operations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Base on the comments on top I guess XMLWriter is better which will give me better memory control and the possible problem of string is concatenation memory allocation for a long string and possibility of using special character. The example I provided is just to clarify my question, otherwise the one I have is totally different and complicated.

Comment: If it is more complicated, you could use a template engine. A lot of node objects + their content *as string* consumes *defintely* more memory than plain string operations, no doubt